# What is the best way to level Co-Op Score in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Personally, I am what they call an *Achievement-whore* or [Formally] a completionist... But Battlefield 3 has taken that to a whole new level.

I think Battlefield 3 has about 367 total available dog tags to obtain.  I know some of them are not possible to get anymore (Dr. Pepper promo, etc) - but there are some that via **math**, I have determined will take a very long time to obtain.

There are co-op service star dog tags at 1, 5, 10, 20, and 50.  From what I have found:

- You'll need 22,000,000 co-op points for service star 50
- Debatable The best level for grinding co-op points is Hit & Run, which can be done for ~10k points in 7min
- You'll have to play that level 2,200 times and spend about 260hr doing it.[[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/621026-/61957501)]

**Is there a better way to grind out the co-op?**  Seeing as they only have a few missions, at 260hrs... I don't think I will have that kind of endurance to obtain those dog tags...

[Here is a crazy big picture of all available dog tags to reference what I am talking about.](http://m2s.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/bf3_dogtags_all.jpg)

Comment: 5 of those tags (Dinosaur, And Counting, Pirate, Razor Blade and the Mayan Tomb) can be acquired through the SPECACTS bundle on Origin. I feel so dirty, promoting Origin like that 8-\

Comment: Did you not see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33966/bf3-coop-points ? Seems like the accepted answer has some good possibilities if those loopholes work and haven't been fixed.

Comment: @AHungerArtist - That to me seems like the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me - easier level is Fire from the sky - safe and could be very fast with good flight skills. With known friend (not a random pilot\gunner) and voice chat you can split attack areas and eliminate npcs much faster. Average I got 12k per flight, dont remeber how long it could take, but leveling for unlocks was pretty fast. projecting on the many repeats - 20% more exp and guaranted safe completion worth this.

Comment: but still... thats 200+ hours of co-op alone?!

Comment: Probably - yes, even more.

We didnt asked you about why you want that achievement =), just answered your question. Its your time and you could choose any way to spend\waste it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is an easy way to work your way up to the dog tags.

All of the ways require work (unless you want to cheat which may cause you to forfeit your progress entirely). Your best bet is to find a level you are comfortable with playing and find a capable team mate to help you do so. If you become an expert at a level then you may be able to find ways to speed it up by coordinating with your team mate or skipping unessential combat.

What is unessential combat? If you see your objective to the west but enemies to the north, you can avoid them if you have good cover leading you closer to the objective.

You could also speed up the time by becoming efficient with your guns (obviously). If you can aim down sight and engage an enemy quickly and accurately, you will split time off of the mission. Conserving ammo also helps as you wont be screwed over when you have to reload in a hectic combat situation.

Getting to your goal isn't going to be easy. If it was, it wouldn't be special or worth a celebrating.

Answer (score 1):

I too would suggest Fire From the Sky. Looking at my Friends Leaderboard, the highest there is approx 47k points. Once you play through it a few times and know where all the enemies appear from, it shouldn't take that long to complete.

Comment: The 47k is across all difficulties - so multiple plays.  We almost have that one down to a science from where they spawn.